# How to embed a graphical interactive IronPython shell in an application?

Tags: python, shell, ironpython, embedding, read-eval-print-loop

I've tried the obvious path in my pet open source project [RevitPythonShell](http://code.google.com/p/revitpythonshell/) (a plugin for the building modeling software Autodesk Revit Architecture 2010): `code.interact()` with the IronPython engine set up to use .NET streams for `STDIN` and `STDOUT`. These I then redirect to a `TextBox` control. It kinda works, but really is only an ugly hack.

The main problem is getting all the shell stuff to work: Up-arrow and down-arrow for history, editing, copy & paste, EOF, syntax highlighting, tool tips etc. **It takes a lot of work to get this right**, and it is not really the problem I'm trying to solve (I'm trying to get an interactive shell hosted in Revit, not make the perfect shell GUI).

If this weren't a .NET project, I'd probably look into reusing [PyCrust/PyWrap](http://www.wxpython.org/py.php), but I'm not sure if that can be done from a WinForms project. Is there anything similar for .NET?

Has anyone ever implemented the `IConsole` interface and can show an example of what I'd need to do? It seems this would be the proper route to go (as opposed to using the `code` module), but for the life of me I can't figure it out. IronPython source code has no comments whatsoever.

**UPDATE:** After trying out some stuff, I eventually settled on the superb [IronLab](http://ironlab.net/) code. It includes an example shell with syntax highlighting and all. The code was nice and easy to integrate. Check the RevitPythonShell code on hints on how to embed it.

Comment: Not really a nice canned solution...so I'll leave it as a comment.  You could look at Matt Ward's PythonConsole.cs source in the SharpDevelop IDE project.  Look in SharpDevelop\src\AddIns\BackendBindings\Python\PythonBinding\Project\Src.  It might be a big problem to break this class out so that it (and the ICSharpCode.TextEditor) can be used in other projects.  But perhaps it will help you out a bit.  Download the SharpDevelop source from their build server: http://build.sharpdevelop.net/BuildArtefacts or use svn at: svn://svnmirror.sharpdevelop.net/sharpdevelop/branches/3.0/SharpDevelop

Comment: don't be shy ;) this is a very good answer in its own right - I will have a look into it as soon as I get around to doing so!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for a similar thing and I discovered that the IronLab project contains a nice IronPython console. The source code can be found here https://github.com/rwg0/ironlab/tree/master/IronPythonConsole.

[edit on 25/10/2016] fixed broken url

Comment: right, i actually moved to this about a year ago, but forgot to update my question. thanks for documenting it for the rest of the world. the IronPythonConsole from the IronLab project is a gem! You can see an example of embedding it in your own project in the RevitPythonShell project.

Comment: This link is dead, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, then I have two possible answers.  One in the comment above....and another far simpler (no intellisense, no syntax highlighting):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/irontextbox2.aspx

It's by JoeSox, and it is for IronPython 2, not 2.6.  However I was able to update it to work properly with 2.6 in about five minutes.  If you are interested I can figure out a way to send you a diff file or slap the updated project somewhere (it was published under an MIT license).

Enjoy!

David

Comment: sweet :) just what I was looking for! Will report back here when I get it running!

Comment: you can look at the source of the RevitPythonShell (http://revitpythonshell.googlecode.com) for an idea of how to integrate this the IronTextBox2 control...